# Getting error: dockergitlab_gitlab_1 exited with code 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am facing this issue when i run `docker-compose up` command. 
Basically i am using the gitlab using this [link](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) and using external mysql/postgres database. And here how my `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis:Z
  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:11.5.1
    depends_on:
    - redis    
    ports:
    - "10080:80"
    - "10022:22"
  volumes:
    - /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data:Z
    environment:
    - DEBUG=true
    - DB_ADAPTER=mysql2
    - DB_HOST=<ip address of mysql>
    - DB_PORT=3306
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379
    - GITLAB_HOST=localhost
    - GITLAB_PORT=10080
    - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022
    - GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=<KEY>
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=<KEY>
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=<KEY>
```

### Getting logs like below

[image: log image]

After enabling the `--env 'DEBUG=true` getting like and it keeps on running it again and again. Dont know where am doing wrong. Can any one help me with this

```
+ export GITLAB_INSTALL_DIR GITLAB_SHELL_INSTALL_DIR GITLAB_DATA_DIR GITLAB_REPOS_DIR GITLAB_DOWNLOADS_DIR GITLAB_SHARED_DIR GITLAB_HOST GITLAB_PORT GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT GITLAB_HTTPS GITLAB_SSH_HOST GITLAB_SSH_PORT GITLAB_SIGNUP_ENABLED GITLAB_PROJECTS_LIMIT GITLAB_USERNAME_CHANGE GITLAB_CREATE_GROUP
+ local IFS=:
+ sudo -HEu git envsubst '$GITLAB_INSTALL_DIR:$GITLAB_SHELL_INSTALL_DIR:$GITLAB_DATA_DIR:$GITLAB_REPOS_DIR:$GITLAB_DOWNLOADS_DIR:$GITLAB_SHARED_DIR:$GITLAB_HOST:$GITLAB_PORT:$GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT:$GITLAB_HTTPS:$GITLAB_SSH_HOST:$GITLAB_SSH_PORT:$GITLAB_SIGNUP_ENABLED:$GITLAB_PROJECTS_LIMIT:$GITLAB_USERNAME_CHANGE:$GITLAB_CREATE_GROUP'
+ rm -f /tmp/tmp.fJRiqAUhiC
+ gitlab_configure_database
+ echo -n 'Configuring gitlab::database'
+ gitlab_finalize_database_parameters
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ -z localhost ]]
+ DB_ADAPTER=mysql2
+ case ${DB_ADAPTER} in
+ DB_ENCODING=utf8
+ DB_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci
+ DB_PORT=3306
+ DB_USER=gitlab
+ DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
+ gitlab_check_database_connection
+ case ${DB_ADAPTER} in
+ prog='mysqladmin -h localhost -P 3306 -u gitlab -p password status'
+ timeout=60
+ mysqladmin -h localhost -P 3306 -u gitlab -p password status
++ expr 60 - 1
+ timeout=59
+ [[ 59 -eq 0 ]]
+ echo -n .
+ sleep 1
+ mysqladmin -h localhost -P 3306 -u gitlab -p password status
++ expr 59 - 1
+ timeout=58
+ [[ 58 -eq 0 ]]
+ echo -n .
+ sleep 1

+ mysqladmin -h localhost -P 3306 -u gitlab -ppassword status
++ expr 1 - 1
+ timeout=0
Configuring 
gitlab::database...........................................................
```

`
then container exited.

Comment: Where i have to place the `network_mode: host` in the above yml file? to use the locally hosted mysql/postgres database

Comment: any help on this??

Comment: any help/update on this

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Nope iam still facing this issue